# Active Status - tabs within tabs .js

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

I have borrowed JavaScript from another source and trying to alter it to fit my needs.
I want the parent tab to stay 'active' and the subtabs have a separate 'active' display.
This would help keep users aware as to which main tab they are on.

I am working with a vendor platform that has coding restrictions - which is why some of my code might be over styled.

Any assistance is appreciated :)

```js
function openTab(evt, openTab, subTab) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");

  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  if (subTab) {
    var parent = evt.currentTarget.closest('.tabcontent');
    parent.style.display = "block";
    parent.className += " active";
  }
  document.getElementById(openTab).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

}
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab2 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tab button,
.tab2 button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.tab2 button {
  font-size: 18px !important;
  background-color: #ED780F;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
}

.tab button:hover,
.tab2 button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #000;
}

.tab button.active,
.tab2 button.active {
  background-color: #0f3d70 !important;
  color: #fff;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button type="button" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Assessments')">Assessments</button>
  <button type="button" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Workshops')">Workshops</button>
  <button type="button" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Critical')">Critical Skills</button>
  <button type="button" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Tools')">Tools</button>
</div>

<!--1st Tab-->
<div id="Assessments" class="tabcontent">
  <h1>Assessments</h1>
  <h2>Use your results to identify appropriate training on the Tech Development page or other resources within Navy Federal University.</h2>
  <ul class="w3-ul w3-medium half w3-margin-bottom">
    <li>Identify priority skills for your role with your leader.</li>
    <li>Select 2 – 3 assessments to establish your baseline.
    </li>
    <li>Use results to identify appropriate training within the Tech Development School or other resources within The University.
    </li>
    <li>Retake original assessment to evaluate learning progress.
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!--Assessment SubTab-->
  <div class="tab2">
    <button type="button" class="tablinks small" onclick="openTab(event, 'data',true)">Data Analytics Skills Survey</button>
    <button type="button" class="tablinks small" onclick="openTab(event, 'DataCamp', true)">DataCamp</button>
    <button type="button" class="tablinks small" onclick="openTab(event, 'LinkedIn', true)">LinkedIn</button>
  </div>

  <!--Data Skills Survey SubTab-->
  <div id="data" class="tabcontent">
    <div class="row">
      <h2 class="half">Interested in future data and analytics development opportunities?
        <br>
        <br>
        <a class="ulink" href="6" target="_blank">Click here</a> to learn about the Data and Analytics Skills Survey, review FAQs and access a link to complete the survey
      </h2>

      <img class="sammie" src="" alt="sammie">
    </div>
  </div>


  <!--DataCamp SubTab-->
  <div id="DataCamp" class="tabcontent">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="half">
        <i class="brand fad fa-campground"></i>
        <h2>Discover your analytical skill level and receive personalized learning recommendations with DataCamp’s assessments.</h2>
        <a class="ubutton" href="s" target="_blank">View Available Asssesments</a>
      </div>

      <ul class="list half">
        <h2><b>Examples include:</b></h2>
        <li>R</li>
        <li>SQL</li>
        <li>Python</li>
        <li>Data &amp; Analytics</li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>


  <!--LinkedIn SubTab-->
  <div id="LinkedIn" class="tabcontent">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="half">
        <i class="brand fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
        <h2>LinkedIn allows learners to take assessments on business and technical skills to test and showcase their proficiency in those skills. LinkedIn Learning will recommend courses for you and skill badges are available to display on your profile.
          <br>
          <br>
          <i>Must be logged into LinkedIn. <a class="ulink" href="" target="_blank">Click here</a> for instructions for activating your account.</i>
        </h2>

        <a class="ubutton" href="" target="_blank">View Available Asssesments</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="list half">
        <h2><b>Examples include:</b></h2>
        <li>Agile Methodologies</li>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>C#</li>
        <li>C++</li>
        <li>CSS</li>
        <li>Hadoop</li>
        <li>Java</li>
        <li>JavaScript</li>
        <li>Machine Learning</li>
        <li>Microsoft Azure</li>
        <li>Microsoft Excel</li>
        <li>Microsoft Power BI</li>
        <li>Microsoft SharePoint</li>
        <li>MongoDB</li>
        <li>Python</li>
        <li>R Programming</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please may you check the example? It currently has errors.

Comment: Also this is not a great pattern: `tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");` instead use [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and `document.querySelectorAll(".tablinks").forEach(tl => tl.classList.remove("active"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your actual code an easy way to achieve what you want is handling independently the `active` class on tabs and subtabs buttons.
First assign a dedicated class to subtabs buttons, lets say `subtablinks`:

```
<button type="button"
    class="subtablinks small"
    onclick="openTab(event, 'data',true)">
        Data Analytics Skills Survey
</button>
```

Then in your `openTab()` function you can remove the class from tabs or subtabs based on the `subTab` flag:

```
function openTab(evt, openTab, subTab) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks, subtablinks; // Added var for subtablinks
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName('tabcontent');
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = 'none';
  }

  if (subTab) {
    // Removing active class from subtablinks
    subtablinks = document.querySelectorAll('.subtablinks');
    subtablinks.forEach((el) => el.classList.remove('active'));

    var parent = evt.currentTarget.closest('.tabcontent');
    parent.style.display = 'block';
    parent.className += ' active';
  } else {
    // Removing active class from tablinks
    tablinks = document.querySelectorAll('.tablinks');
    tablinks.forEach((el) => el.classList.remove('active'));
  }
  document.getElementById(openTab).style.display = 'block';
  evt.currentTarget.className += ' active';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not trivial but this works

1. Using addEventListener
2. delegating from a wrapper (I added a div)
3. Using closest
4. toggling hidden

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("button");
  if (tgt) {
    const id = tgt.dataset.id;
    const subTab = tgt.classList.contains("small");
    document.querySelectorAll(".tabcontent").forEach(tc => {
      const hide = id != tc.id && !(subTab && tc === tgt.closest(".tabcontent"))
      tc.hidden = hide
    });
    document.querySelectorAll(".tablinks").forEach(tl => tl.classList.toggle("active", tgt === tl));
    if (subTab) document.querySelector(`[data-id=${tgt.closest(".tabcontent").id}]`).classList.add("active")
    else document.getElementById(id)?.querySelector(".tablinks").click()
  }
})
document.querySelector(".tablinks").click()
```

```css
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab2 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tab button,
.tab2 button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.tab2 button {
  font-size: 18px !important;
  background-color: #ED780F;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
}

.tab button:hover,
.tab2 button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #000;
}

.tab button.active,
.tab2 button.active {
  background-color: #0f3d70 !important;
  color: #fff;
}

.tabcontent {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="tab">
    <button type="button" class="tablinks" data-id="Assessments">Assessments</button>
    <button type="button" class="tablinks" data-id="Workshops">Workshops</button>
    <button type="button" class="tablinks" data-id="Critical">Critical Skills</button>
    <button type="button" class="tablinks" data-id="Tools">Tools</button>
  </div>

  <!--1st Tab-->
  <div id="Assessments" class="tabcontent">
    <h1>Assessments</h1>
    <h2>Use your results to identify appropriate training on the Tech Development page or other resources within Navy Federal University.</h2>
    <ul class="w3-ul w3-medium half w3-margin-bottom">
      <li>Identify priority skills for your role with your leader.</li>
      <li>Select 2 – 3 assessments to establish your baseline.
      </li>
      <li>Use results to identify appropriate training within the Tech Development School or other resources within The University.
      </li>
      <li>Retake original assessment to evaluate learning progress.
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!--Assessment SubTab-->
    <div class="tab tab2">
      <button type="button" class="tablinks small" data-id="data">Data Analytics Skills Survey</button>
      <button type="button" class="tablinks small" data-id="DataCamp">DataCamp</button>
      <button type="button" class="tablinks small" data-id="LinkedIn">LinkedIn</button>
    </div>

    <!--Data Skills Survey SubTab-->
    <div id="data" class="tabcontent">
      <div class="row">
        <h2 class="half">Interested in future data and analytics development opportunities?
          <br>
          <br>
          <a class="ulink" href="6" target="_blank">Click here</a> to learn about the Data and Analytics Skills Survey, review FAQs and access a link to complete the survey
        </h2>

        <img class="sammie" src="" alt="sammie">
      </div>
    </div>


    <!--DataCamp SubTab-->
    <div id="DataCamp" class="tabcontent">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="half">
          <i class="brand fad fa-campground"></i>
          <h2>Discover your analytical skill level and receive personalized learning recommendations with DataCamp’s assessments.</h2>
          <a class="ubutton" href="s" target="_blank">View Available Asssesments</a>
        </div>

        <ul class="list half">
          <h2><b>Examples include:</b></h2>
          <li>R</li>
          <li>SQL</li>
          <li>Python</li>
          <li>Data &amp; Analytics</li>
        </ul>

      </div>

    </div>


    <!--LinkedIn SubTab-->
    <div id="LinkedIn" class="tabcontent">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="half">
          <i class="brand fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
          <h2>LinkedIn allows learners to take assessments on business and technical skills to test and showcase their proficiency in those skills. LinkedIn Learning will recommend courses for you and skill badges are available to display on your profile.
            <br>
            <br>
            <i>Must be logged into LinkedIn. <a class="ulink" href="" target="_blank">Click here</a> for instructions for activating your account.</i>
          </h2>

          <a class="ubutton" href="" target="_blank">View Available Asssesments</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="list half">
          <h2><b>Examples include:</b></h2>
          <li>Agile Methodologies</li>
          <li>C</li>
          <li>C#</li>
          <li>C++</li>
          <li>CSS</li>
          <li>Hadoop</li>
          <li>Java</li>
          <li>JavaScript</li>
          <li>Machine Learning</li>
          <li>Microsoft Azure</li>
          <li>Microsoft Excel</li>
          <li>Microsoft Power BI</li>
          <li>Microsoft SharePoint</li>
          <li>MongoDB</li>
          <li>Python</li>
          <li>R Programming</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```